# Can't create folder using mkdir

Tags: command-line, filesystem, mkdir

I want to create a folder following the below procedure:

```
set folder 2017/October/10
mkdir $folder
```

But this isn't possible and I get the message:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '2017/October/10': No such file or directory
```

I want to include that in script function! I could really use some help!

EDIT: This just can't happen!

Comment: Same result. It didn't work.

Comment: That is not a good name, it will cause problems. You can try `mkdir '2017/October/10'` but imho better use a different delineate 2017.October.10 for exame

Comment: I'd recommend ISO-8601 format for naming files and dirs, so in this case: `2017-10-10`

Comment: Forward slashes aren't allowed in file or directory names on any variant of Unix (including Linux).  Even if individual filesystems support it (and the main ones don't), the operating system doesn't.  I'd recommend dashes instead.

Answer (score 3):

The `/` character is used to separate the different directories, and it fails because the directory `2017` does not yet exist. To create nested directories with the parent directories created automatically, use

```
mkdir -p 2017/October/10
```

Comment: I want the name of the directory to be 2017/October/10. I don't want to create a folder and then subfolders within it.

Comment: @TeoProtoulis You can't do that. (Edit: sorry for the all-caps)

Comment: @wjandrea Yes, I figured that out. Thanks anyway!